# Is it true that the group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ under addition has elements of order $n$ $\forall $ $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My intuition says that yes, it has to be true, but I'm not sure how to deal with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ Any hints would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you find an element of order 709?

Comment: Let $n$ be your favourite positive integer. Think about which real numbers $x$ have $nx\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: …aaaaaaand the question was ruined for you. This site is great :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of $1/n$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$  has order $n$.